# Pagination CodeIgniter overwriting the base URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

My website pagination is inside the "home" function in the "user_area" controller file.
I followed the example from this page [Pagination](http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/)

The pagination works fine except that it messes my base_url. When I click the pagination links, and then click on a link in the website navbar, the "home" is added to all the links.

Any help is welcome.

Controller:

```
    public function home(){
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){

        $this->load->model('model_match');
        $this->load->model('model_user');
        $this->load->model('model_msg');    

        $pagination = array();

        $pagination["total_rows"] = $this->model_match->countMatches();
        $pagination["per_page"] = 2;
        $pagination["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $choice = $pagination["total_rows"] / $pagination["per_page"];
        $pagination["num_links"] = round($choice);
        $pagination['base_url'] = base_url('user_area/home');
        $this->pagination->initialize($pagination);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data["videos"] =  $this->model_match->getAllMatches($pagination["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();


        $data['count_unread_msgs'] = $this->model_msg->countUnreadMsgs($this->session->userdata('user'));
        $data['count_unread_hearts'] = $this->model_msg->countUnreadHearts($this->session->userdata('user'));



        $data['user_name'] = $this->session->userdata('user');
        //$data['videos'] = $this->model_match->getAllMatches();
        $this->load->view('user/matches',$data);

        }else{
            redirect('home');
            }

    }
```

Nav Bar :

```
        <nav>      


                 <a  href="home">Home</a>   
                  <a  href="message_center">Messages</a>   
                 <a href="account">Account</a>

                   <a   href="library">Portfolio</a>
                 <a   href="favorites">Favorites</a>   
                 <a href="viewer-help.php">Help / FAQ </a> -->
                 <a  href="toolkit">Toolkit</a>   
                   <a href="<?php echo base_url()."login/logout";?>">Logout</a>


                <?php searchOptions();?>

    </nav>
```

Comment: sounds like your navbar code is the problem.  post it?

Comment: I just edited the post. All the links are routed inside the user_area controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

theres your problem

`<a  href="toolkit">Toolkit</a>` is a relative path link,

you should be doing something like this on all your nav links as a best practice:

`<a href="<?php echo base_url('toolkit');?>">Toolkit</a>`

or

`<a href="<?=base_url('toolkit');?>">Toolkit</a>`

if your server supports short open tags

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked! Still I dont understand why it was appending the "home" to the other links.

Comment: @MichelFigueiredo its because you previously had relative path links.  IE.  they just tak themselves on to whatever the current url of the loaded page is.  Now you have absolute path links, that specify the full path to the page.  Absolute paths in tandem with code igniters base url function being editable in the config file, make for a sturdy portable link structure!